# expected value of permutation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose you have a set X with 2 or greater distinct values and x1,x2...xn are permutations of set X. For i=2,3,...n the position i in the permutation is a step if xi−1<xi. Position 1 is also considered a step. What is the expected value of steps in random permutation of X?

Please explain if possible.

So far I solved by brute force so when n=2 I got 3 steps. So probability 3/2

For n=3 I got 12/6 and so on.

I noticed the denominator is changing by n! but I cannot find the correlation in the numerator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected value in a random permutation of a set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891443/expected-value-in-a-random-permutation-of-a-set)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1,2,3$, and $4$ one gets $\frac11,\frac32,\frac{12}6$, and $\frac{60}{24}$, respectively. The ratios between consecutive values are $\frac32,\frac43$, and $\frac54$. We have pretty minimal data, but there is a pattern there: it suggests that there are altogether $\frac{(n+1)!}2$ steps in the $n!$ permutations of $[n]$. One might reasonably try to prove this by induction on $n$.

SKETCH: Suppose that $n>1$, and there are $\frac{n!}2$ steps in the $(n-1)!$ permutations of $[n-1]$; then there are

$$\begin{align*}
(n-1)(n-1)!-\frac{n!}2&=\left((n-1)-\frac{n}2\right)(n-1)!\\
&=\left(\frac{n}2-1\right)(n-1)!
\end{align*}$$

non-steps in those permutations, and the same number of non-steps in the permutations of $\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$.

Each permutation of $[n]$ can be obtained uniquely by inserting a $1$ into a permutation of $\{2,\ldots,n\}$. Show that inserting the $1$ adds a step if and only if we insert it at the front or before a non-step, and use this to complete the induction step by showing that there are $\frac{(n+1)!}2$ steps in the $n!$ permutations of $[n]$.